# Why does Update() call itself more than once?

Tags: c#, list, count, unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity and developing a cricket game. I have a screen that shows squad selection. It shows images of 15 players, out of which I have to select any 11.

I keep on adding the clicked (selected) player in a List. But the problem is that when I click the player once, the size of my list becomes 4 or 5 or even more sometimes. My script is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class bear : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        //select ();
        if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);
            if (collider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
            {
                Material newMat = Resources.Load("New Material", typeof(Material)) as Material;
                gameObject.renderer.material = newMat;
                PlayersManager.objPlayerList.Add(PlayersManager.setPlayerObject("Bear"));
                countausplayer.countteam++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me where am I going wrong? Why is the List size increasing on its own?

Comment: How many frames do you have? "Update is called once per frame. It is the main workhorse function for frame updates." see http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: This isn't related to your question directly, but I'd move `Material newMat = Resources.Load("New Material", typeof(Material)) as Material;` out of your Update, since it's a fairly expensive operation. ``Material newMat` can be a memeber, and you can set it in `Awake`. And maybe cache the renderer variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update is called every frame, and you are testing basically **every frame** if the users finger is over your item and adding items to the list. If you have a long touch you will get more adds.

instead you should test that the touch has ended, you do this with TouchPhase.

The right **TouchPhase** is `TouchPhase.Ended`.

This means that a finger was lifted from the screen. This is the final phase of a touch.

Or in your code:

```
void Update () {
    //select ();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < Input.touchCount) {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(i).position);
            Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);
            if (collider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos))
            {
                Material newMat = Resources.Load("New Material", typeof(Material)) as Material;
                gameObject.renderer.material = newMat;
                PlayersManager.objPlayerList.Add(PlayersManager.setPlayerObject("Bear"));
                countausplayer.countteam++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was wrong...

I think you have the solution here:

- http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zszQA9httVo

You should look for `Input.touchCount > 0 && TouchPhase.TheOneYouWant`